# Formula that returns a user's manager

Tags: formula, formula-field

I need a formula that return’s a user’s manager from the user’s profile page in a custom field on the opportunity split object. I’m sure this is a simple formula, but I don’t know how to write it.

Comment: What user's Manager? The Opportunity Owner? The Current User?

Comment: are you not getting this with  SplitOwner.Manager.Id  ?

Comment: the manager thats in the "manager" field on the user's profile page

Comment: I want to write a formula that looks at the team member on the opportunity split object and inserts the value in the “managers” field on  that users profile page.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a formula field that results in a lookup relationship field, but you can use the following formula to concatenate the first and last name fields:

```
SplitOwner.Manager.FirstName & " " & SplitOwner.Manager.LastName
```

The easiest way to get this is to use the Advanced Formula tab and click the Insert Field button, then follow the path to the Manager:

[image: Formula field picker shows Opportunity Split - Team Member - Manager - First Name]

If you want the field to link to the Manager's profile, you can use the HYPERLINK formula function as follows:

```
HYPERLINK("/" &  SplitOwner.ManagerId, SplitOwner.Manager.FirstName & " " & SplitOwner.Manager.LastName)
```

More info on:

- [Concatenation operator](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#Concatenate)
- [HYPERLINK formula function](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK)

Comment: Do I need to close this question or select a best answer like on the Salesforce community?

Comment: Excellent, and welcome to Salesforce StackExchange! Yes, please mark that this answers your question. Also, one difference in the StackExchange community from the Salesforce community is that comments that say things like "thank you" that don't offer additional information or context are frowned on as cruft. Marking the answer as accepted is considered thanks enough.